# How I can solve $\log_{\frac{1}{(2+|x|)}}(5+x^2)=\log_{(3+x^2)}(15+\sqrt x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, quadratics

I don't know how to solve this. I have tried base change but it's not working. Please provide a solution.

Comment: What  have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried base change but it's not working

Comment: Question as it is is very unclear, what is base , etc

Comment: It's 1/2+|x| and 3+x^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that right side is only defined for $x\ge 0$, so we may restrict our analysis there. Now, on the right side, $15+\sqrt x \gt 1$ so right hand side is always positive.

On the other hand, left side, we have for $x> 0$, $$\log_{\tfrac{1}{1+2|x|}}(5+x^2) = -\log_{1+2x}(5+x^2)$$ and since $1+2x < 5+x^2$, so $\log_{1+2x}(5+x^2)$ is always positive and left hand side is always negative. There are no solutions.